# Maximum number of tabs & color of line under tabs?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have 2 questions on TabHost.

1. Is there a maximum number of tabs which we can add via `tabHost.addTab(spec)`? I need up to 10 tabs.
2. I have managed to change the color of each tab and tab divider, but I still cannot change the color of grey line under the tabs (under each unselected tab)). What is the name of that line? Can I change its color or even completely remove it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no hard limit but Google suggests a maximum of 4 tabs. You always have to keep in mind your tabs need to be large enough to be clickable.

Concerning your second question you can disable it using the [android:tabStripEnabled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabWidget.html#attr_android:tabStripEnabled) XML attribute.